# HubSpot - create 2 ticket property of type dropdown with external data source and parent child relationship

Tags: hubspot, hubspot-crm, hubspot-api, hubspot-cms

I am using HubSpot portal. I have 2 queries related to property.

1. I want to create a custom ticket property of type dropdown, and want to fill its options with data from external source (which is my server's API). Currently I am able to create property, but there is not any options to get the options by external source.
   [image]
2. My second query is also related to property. So that I want to create 2 dropdown type property, and on selection of option in 1st dropdown want to filter/populate options in second dropdown.

Please help me to find out these queries. Is it possible or not?

Thanks,